# How to create Border on a input td in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I created a table in which I want the user be able to give inputs. Now when a td is selected/focused i want to turn the border around it in a color. I already tried that, but when I do that it leaves a thin gap between the inputfield and the td, even if I have set the padding to 0.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900');
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

input {
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {}

table {
  margin: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  font-size: 20px;
}

td:focus {
  border: 1.5px solid orange;
}

td,
th {
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Income</th>
      <th>Outgoings</th>
      <th>Taxes</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="CHF"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="CHF"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="CHF"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="CHF"></td>
    </tr>
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: What's that for `input:focus {}`?

Comment: `1.5px solid orange`... `1.5` px like 1 px and half the other?

Comment: Have you tried with `input:focus {box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px orange;}` ?

Comment: Instead of using an input element you can make the `<td contenteditable="true">`

Comment: @enxaneta contenteditable is a beast, it multilines, adds tags, bolds, italicizes, makes coffee and other unwanted stuff.

Comment: `td` can by default not have `:focus`, generally only form elements and anchor can. Instead use the `outline` property on the `input`, e.g. `input:focus {
  outline: 3px solid orange;
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `box-shadow` to the `:focus`ed input.
Box shadow  will overlap the parent TD's gray borders giving the desired effect.
It also prevents from moving things around (2px or so) since box-shadow will not trigger a reflow. It just paints.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900');
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

input {
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow:  0 0 0 1px orange;
}

table {
  margin: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  font-size: 20px;
}

td,
th {
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Income</th>
    <th>Outgoings</th>
    <th>Taxes</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="CHF"></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="CHF"></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="CHF"></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="CHF"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TD can get `:focus` only if you set a `tabindex` property to it. But since it's child is an input, that input will steal the `focus`, never propagating to TD.

Comment: Thank you. Worked.

Comment: But can you maybe explain why it didn't work with border? And why it works with box-shadow?

Comment: @Predecitedq you're welcome. Added a line of info... if it helps.

Comment: Thx, so with parent you mean the white gap which was between?

Comment: @Predecitedq by input parent I mean the TD parent element.

Comment: @Predecitedq actually, the TD never gets focused in your example. The Input steals the focus. If you try to set focus via dev-tools on the td, you will see it "works".

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm just dumb right now, but what is the parent element?

Comment: A parent element is whatever element encapsulates a child element. In your case INPUT is a child of TD. TD is it's parent. Also, what Sølve Tornøe said. You cannot get a TD to get `:focus` because, logically, the INPUT got it first and TD has no `tabindex` property set.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clearifying that. Thanks both of u for helping.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan A question, above you mentioned something about the 1.5 px? Is that something you shouldn't do? Or what you ment by "taking the half of the other".

Comment: @Predecitedq since *px* is a unit for physical screen pixels use integers, not floats. You'll have always the desired result crossbrowser.